# ComboBox error when setting scrollbox value in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

On a Form I am using a ComboBox to search a text range and return that row value.  The ScrollBox value is then set to the row value.  My minimum row value is 5 and the max value is done by a row.count which happens to be 28.  When I run the code the ScrollBar works fine until my value gets over 23, the scrollbar.value resets to 7 and starts all over again.  Using the combobox to set the row value has the same problem as well and I am unable to search the whole text range.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()


g = ScrollBar1.Value
StrtComboBox.Value = Sheets("Main").Cells(g, 6).Value
Plyr1Lbl.Caption = Sheets("Main").Cells(g, 7).Value
Plyr2Lbl.Caption = Sheets("Main").Cells(g, 8).Value
Plyr3Lbl.Caption = Sheets("Main").Cells(g, 9).Value
Plyr4Lbl.Caption = Sheets("Main").Cells(g, 10).Value

TextBox9.Value = ScrollBar1.Value
TextBox10.Value = ScrollBar1.Max


End Sub

Private Sub StrtComboBox_Change()
Sheets("Main").Activate


LastHoleRow = Sheets("Main").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
Names.Add Name:="Holes", RefersTo:=Range("F5:F" & LastHoleRow)

Dim BoxValue As Range
    With Range("Holes")
    Set BoxValue = .Find(StrtComboBox.Value)
    If BoxValue Is Nothing Then
    Else

   ScrollBar1.Value = BoxValue.Row
   End If
   End With

End Sub
```

[image: Main Sheet]

[image: UserForm]

Comment: What's on your "main" worksheet in column F? does it do anything unexpected after F23?

Comment: @CallumDA Column F is a list that continues all the way to F28. After row 28 the column is blank.  I created a named range from F5:F28.

Comment: I am trying to understand exactly what your code is doing but it's quite confusing. Can you add some screenshots of your worksheet and the form?

Comment: @CallumDA the first is a screen shot of the "Main" sheet.  The Named range Holes is selected.  Second screen shot is the form itself.  I use the drop down combo to find the hole assignment on the main sheet and return the row value to the Scrollbar to update the form.  It works until the value exceeds 23.  As a side note, when I eliminate Sub StrtComboBox_Change() everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for that -- the problem is much clearer now. Try out my solution and let me know how if it works?

Comment: Works perfect.  My skills are not as advance as I'd like.  Only been using VBA for 8 or 9 months. I'm learning all the time.  I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for `8A` and expecting to find it in `F24`, however it can be found earlier in `F7` which has value `18A` (since `8A` can be found in the string `18A`).

The fix should be simple. The `.Find` method has a `.LookAt` parameter which determines whether a complete match must be made. So just change

```
Set BoxValue = .Find(StrtComboBox.Value)
```

to this

```
Set BoxValue = .Find(What:=StrtComboBox.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```